# Need help in Laravel Eloquent for Multiple Join

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables. `Events`, `Events_join` , `Customers` . in `event_join` I have only customer id those who join the event. currently, I fetching events with an array of `events_join` using this
my DB structure is:
**Table structure for table `my_events`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sdes` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pic` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sdate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
  `edate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `des` varchar(10000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cat` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Table structure for table `customers`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `phone` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `city` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pic` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Table structure for table `events_join`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events_join` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eventid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sdate` date NOT NULL,
  `edate` date NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My Events model have this

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Events::class,EventsJoin::class);
}
```

My Customer model have this

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class,EventsJoin::class);
}
```

My EventsJoin have this Pivot

```
 public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}

public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Events::class);
}
```

my eventControler have this

```
$events=Customer::with(['event']);
```

but its return empty record. the way its working is customers can create events and other customers will join the event. currently those join the events save with userid in `events_join` table. I want to join `events_join` table with the `customers` table so that I can get additional information of the customer.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what you want. Do you want a list of customers for an event?

Comment: Yes, i  want list of events with customers aray those join the events

Comment: Do you means of userid is the id in `customers` table?

Answer (score 0):

While not mentioned in your code, I would have to guess that you have 3 Models, one Events, another one for EventsJoin and one for Customers.

What you seem to have, although you don't say it, is a Many to Many relationship in which a Customer can be in Multiple Events and an Event can be joined by Multiple customers.

In Laravel eloquent terms a Many for Many relationship is described with a **belongsToMany**.
Take a look at the documentation:  https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Because it is a Many to Many relationship, the **EventsJoin** needs to extend **Pivot** and not **Model**.

So you would have in your **Customer** Model something like:

```
public function events()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class,EventsJoin::class);
}
```

And in your **EventsJoin** Pivot model

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}

public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```

And in your **Events** Model

```
public function customers()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class,EventsJoin::class);
}
```

When you wish to get the array of event objects you would do **$customer->events**;
And when you wish to get the array of customers from the event you would do **$event->customers**;

Do note that plural and singular cases are important for Laravel Eloquent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i just update my question in detail. i follow your stuff but no luck. i update now with db structure. please help me where i am wrong.

Comment: It won't work because you are using non-standard names.  
For example:  if you create a Model called Event  (singular), Laravel Eloquent expects a table named events (plural).  You called your table my_events.  Laravel won't find it.  You can tell Laravel the name of the table by using  protected $table = 'my_events';  Please read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions  But of course now you are complicating things a bit.  Also your foreign key fields, Laravel expectes an _ in between user id, so it should be user_id  for example.  You can also override that.

Comment: Another observation is that you have userId in the my_events table, but you also have userId under events_join.  So which one is it?  What is the idea behind userId inside the my_events table?   Also, related to the comment above.  Is it a customer or is it a user?  Laravel will not magically figure out that Customer is User.  If you are relating a Customer with an Event, it expects  customer_id  not user_id.  So I do believe you need to get your database structure cleaned up and figured out first, which is outside the scope of the original question.